Dell Optiplex Desktops Preventing Wake On LAN despite BIOS settings
I have a Proxmox Cluster setup comprised of three Dell Optiplex mid tower units (2 3070's and 1 3060) and one Lenovo m625q. The m625q stays on all the time as a "Controller" node for the Cluster and a host for the VM running my Tailscale VPN.
The three Dell Optiplex nodes are configured with Wake On LAN enabled in the BIOS, Deep Sleep Control disabled, and Block Sleep Enabled. Wake On LAN works when the system is first getting power after being unplugged (Such as during a power outage or when it's being moved); The NIC turns on though the system remains offline, and sending the Wake On LAN command from Proxmox works just fine. However shutting down a node from Proxmox causes the NIC to shut down as well, and nothing I do seems to stop this from happening.
Why are the NIC's shutting down with Proxmox even though the BIOS is configured for Wake On LAN, and how can I resolve this?'
Some Clarifiers - The NIC's work fine when the system is booted up, when in OS I have not had any issues so far. It's when the system shuts down that the NIC's also shut down, despite the BIOS being told to not shut them down.
The Controller stays on at all times, but the Optiplex nodes are meant to be turned off/on at will depending on demand. It is fully manual and I am aware of the dangers that can result from this, I di have a QDevice configured to try and avoid the feared "split brain" scenario and so far I have not regretted the setup. I will like it more when it works correctly, though.

Is WoL enabled for that interface in the OS as well?

@grawity_u1686 yes - unless I'm missing something, WoL is enabled on Proxmox itself and I have hard-coded their MAC addresses so all the systems should know how to speak to each other

@grawity_u1686 I was missing something. Linux newbie here. After adding in the WoL tag in /etc/network/interfaces the NIC's remain active after shutdown. THANK you!

In order to fix this issue I had to enable wake on LAN within Proxmox. I had enabled WoL in the BIOS of all the cluster machines and I had hard-coded the MAC addresses into Proxmox, but Linux requires you to go through a process to enable Wake On LAN within the OS. If you don't do this step, the OS can still shut off the NIC and will not be listening for the magic packet to wake it up.
This is the guide I followed to manually set the network interfaces to enable Wake On LAN at boot time. The important bit is here:
Make sure you have ethtool installed using apt install ethtool
Open the Network Interfaces config using nano /etc/network/interfaces (Make sure if following the website you add an "s" at the end of "interface" or you will get a blank document)
Add in the following under the "iface" line post-up /usr/sbin/ethtool -s <interface_name> wol g, making sure to replace <interface_name> with the correct name of your systems NIC interface
It should look something like mine (Your interface name may be different):
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual
        post-up /usr/sbin/ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.12/25
        gateway 10.0.0.1
        bridge-ports enp1s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

Link to Guide:
https://sabbakix.com/posts/proxmox/proxmox-debian-set-wake-on-lan/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I think giving an example of a valid /etc/networks/interfaces file would be good here

@JourneymanGeek Added - Thank you for the suggestion!
